# Can i delete splits.abi when i only use universal APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, abi

This is my app's `build.gradle`:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Every time build APK, I get 3 APKs.

But, I only use `app-universal-release.apk` for my team.

Can I delete `include "x86", "armeabi-v7a"`, for less build time?

Also, can i delete splits{...} ?

Comment: Hello, do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a flag to my gradle, and pass the flag by `./gradlew assembleDebug -Pflag=true`.

```
android {

  if (flag.toBoolean()) {
    splits {
      abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
      }
    }
  } else {
    defaultConfig.ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
  }

}
```